# Does the IMHO-9000 and Vertix cause friendly fire?

Tags: space-rangers-hd

When attacking a enemy ship I sometimes see an IMHO attack animation hit my partner's ship when they wander too close to my target followed by a damage number.  However when I mouse over them I see no damage.  It could be because their droid is healing it too fast or it is purely cosmetic.  Does the IMHO cause friendly fire?  Does the Vertix have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't *appear* to - just fired five "H" IMHOs (all with Burnz) at a pirate whilst I had five Tranclucators nearby collecting and none of them showed any damage that turn or next.

I'm certain they hadn't (all) been able to repair as one of them still had the 10 repair droid that it started with, even if only one of the shots had hit them they'd have still had some damage.